# How to initialize big thread local objects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local

In a large C++ program, many threads come and go. Using a thread-pool can mitigate this problem a little bit, but for the purpose of this question suppose the total number of threads is a large value, however, only a small number of them are ever used to call a function in `struct TL`. The problem is that `struct TL` contains a few `thread_local` variables of **very large types** (ie, their instances take a lot of memory). So we want is to make sure that only threads that use `struct TL` will construct these objects. Is there any design pattern for this situation? (we do not have control over when a thread is created or destroyed).

An easy solution is shown in the following code:

```
struct TL {
  void func() {
    if(!flag.used) {
      flag.used = true;
      large_1 = new Large_1();
      large_2 = new Large_2(); }
    // use large_1 and large_2
  }
private:
  struct init {
   ~init() {
      delete large_1;
      delete large_2; }
    bool used = false; };

  static thread_local init flag{};
  static thread_local Large_1* large_1 = nullptr;
  static thread_local Large_2* large_2 = nullptr;
};
```

It uses a flag to check if fields are initialized **every time** we interact with `struct TL`. Also, when the thread exists, the destructor of `flag` deletes `large_1` and `large_2`. The problem with this approach is that I have check the flag every time I interact with `struct TL`. I am looking for something like a design pattern for this problem that does not require me to check the flag every time I use `struct TL`.

Comment: Is this `TL` structure created for *every* thread, for most threads, for some extra threads, or only for those threads that actually use this structure? What is this structure used for outside of the threads? If it's only needed be the threads that use this structure, and not used anywhere else, then perhaps a better refactoring is to make sure that only those specific threads that need the structure actually creates it?

Comment: I don't know the structure of the thread. but I think using apointer instead of the object and then constructing the object upon need (using if ) might helps.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like this:

```
struct control_block {
  big_object& get_big_object() {
    if (_big_object == nullptr)
      _big_object = std::make_unique<big_object>();
    return *_big_object;
  }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<big_object> _big_object;
};

static thread_local control_block thread_local_control_block;

auto& big_obj = thread_local_control_block.get_big_object();
```

There is no way to avoid the check if the object is created *on demand*. However, you could specify that a thread that uses this object has to explicitly call some initialization method - then you could replace the `if` with a simple `assert`.

Answer (score 0):

From the question I'm assuming the threaded function takes the form...

```
void worker ()
{
  TL tl;
    .
    .
    .
  if (some_condition_is_met()) {
    tl.func();
  }
}
```

If so you could 'wrap' each data member in a member function that declares a `static thread_local` of the corresponding type -- or `std::unique_ptr` thereof...

```
struct TL {
  void func ()
    {
      auto *large_1 = large_1_instance();
      auto *large_2 = large_2_instance();

      // use large_1 and large_2
  }
private:
  Large_1 *large_1_instance ()
    {
      static thread_local std::unique_ptr<Large_1> ls_instance = std::make_unique<Large_1>();
      return ls_instance.get();
    }

  Large_2 *large_2_instance ()
    {
      static thread_local std::unique_ptr<Large_2> ls_instance = std::make_unique<Large_2>();
      return ls_instance.get();
    }
};
```

So the `Large_N` instances are only created on an as-needed basis and should be destroyed when the thread using the `TL` instance returns.